# bootstrap v4 modal height 100% (media-sensitive)

Tags: modal-dialog, height

How to set height of modal window *min-height* 100% via classes?  For example, `h100` for all screens, and `h100-sm-up`, `h100-md-up`?

It looks very well if modal height is as usual, but at mobile it resizes to 100% height.